# Extra HTML5 Blank Area white spacing

Tags: html, css

my webpage has all of this extra white spacing after my content. If you would paste my code into your IDE and look that would be great! I have tried a few things like make a div around the whole content of the page and set some padding and margin on the bottom but I just can't get it!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/about.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Halong Bay</title>
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index-bay.html">Home</a></li>      
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="map.html">Map</a></li>
                <li><a href="tables.html">Table</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    <section class="intro">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="content">
                <h1>About Halong Bay</h1>
                <a class="btn" href="#link"> get started </a>
                <a class="btn" href="index-bay.html"> Back to Home </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <article>
    <h1>Halong Bay</h1>
    <p id="link"> 
        Ha Long Bay, is in Northeast Vietnam. It is known for its beatiful emerald waters and thousands of towering green limestone islands. It is topped by rainforests, junk boat tours, and sea kayak expeditions. The boat tours takes it visitors past islands named for their shapes, including Stone Dog, and Teapot island. The region is popular for scuba diving, rock climbing, and hiking. It is a really beatiful place to visit and has some most fasinating species of animals that live in this bay.
    </p>
    </article>
    <div id="history">
    <h1>History of Ha Long Bay</h1>
    <p>
        For hundreds of years Halong bay has been an important culture and history of Vietnam. Halong bay also known as Vinh Ha Long, means "Bay of the Descending Dragon". There are approximately 1,969 small islands in this bay. All compromised of differnt sizes and form. These islands have intrigues and amazed locals for hundreds of years. There are over 200 species of fish and over 250 species of mulluks in the water.
    </p>
    </div>


</body>
</html>

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;


}

.intro {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background: url(http://greenhillholidays.info/files/uploads/2016/04/Vietnam-HD-Wallpapers.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    display: table;
}

.intro .inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
}

.content {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.content h1 {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    color: #f9f3f4;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 300px #000;
    font-size: 500%;
}

.btn {
    border-radius: 9px;
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    color: white;
    font-size: 135%;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: solid #036AB1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.btn:hover {
    color: #fff;
    border: solid #fff 3px;
}

p {
    font-size: 160%;
    line-height: 200%;
    margin: 3%;
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    padding: 200px;
}


nav ul li {
    position: relative;
    color: red;
    font-size: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    font-weight: 900;



}

nav ul li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;


}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: blue;

}

.navbar {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;


}

a.btn {
    font-weight: 950;
}

#link {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 100px;

}

p:first-letter {
    font-size: 200%;
}





article {
    padding: 50px;
}

#top1 {

    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;

}

article h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}



#history h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 300px;
}


#history p {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why you had that big empty space, these two things were the problem:

- Using `bottom` w/ padding and relative positioning.
- Using `200px` padding.

You really shouldn't use that much padding on an element.

Here's what, I'm guessing, it should look like:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.intro {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background: url(http://greenhillholidays.info/files/uploads/2016/04/Vietnam-HD-Wallpapers.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  display: table;
}

.intro .inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: none;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.content h1 {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  color: #f9f3f4;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 300px #000;
  font-size: 500%;
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 9px;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  color: white;
  font-size: 135%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: solid #036AB1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border: solid #fff 3px;
}

p {
  font-size: 160%;
  line-height: 200%;
  margin: 3%;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  padding: 20px 200px;
}

nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  font-size: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-weight: 900;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.navbar {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

a.btn {
  font-weight: 950;
}

#link {
  position: relative;
}

p:first-letter {
  font-size: 200%;
}

article {
  padding: 50px;
}

#top1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

article h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#history h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#history p {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/about.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Halong Bay</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index-bay.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="map.html">Map</a></li>
      <li><a href="tables.html">Table</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <section class="intro">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>About Halong Bay</h1>
        <a class="btn" href="#link"> get started </a>
        <a class="btn" href="index-bay.html"> Back to Home </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <article>
    <h1>Halong Bay</h1>
    <p id="link">
      Ha Long Bay, is in Northeast Vietnam. It is known for its beatiful emerald waters and thousands of towering green limestone islands. It is topped by rainforests, junk boat tours, and sea kayak expeditions. The boat tours takes it visitors past islands
      named for their shapes, including Stone Dog, and Teapot island. The region is popular for scuba diving, rock climbing, and hiking. It is a really beatiful place to visit and has some most fasinating species of animals that live in this bay.
    </p>
  </article>
  <div id="history">
    <h1>History of Ha Long Bay</h1>
    <p>
      For hundreds of years Halong bay has been an important culture and history of Vietnam. Halong bay also known as Vinh Ha Long, means "Bay of the Descending Dragon". There are approximately 1,969 small islands in this bay. All compromised of differnt sizes
      and form. These islands have intrigues and amazed locals for hundreds of years. There are over 200 species of fish and over 250 species of mulluks in the water.
    </p>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey man you were absolutely right I actually put that padding there on accident haha! 200 padding is way too much for any HTML element. I had a question though could you clarify why it is bad to use position relative with bottom? When I usually push and pull elements a little bit top, left, right, or bottom I usually give it a position of relative before I do so? Is that incorrect or is there a better way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It didn't say it was _bad_. Using bottom in this case wasn't such a good idea because it was based off the bottom of the screen and not the element below. You should use margin-bottom instead.

Answer (score 0):

When I have checked your code in my system, I have noticed that the issue is coming because of padding and margin settings in your CSS.
I have made few changes in your CSS. try it and still having any issue let me know.

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;


}

.intro {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background: url(http://greenhillholidays.info/files/uploads/2016/04/Vietnam-HD-Wallpapers.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    display: table;
}

.intro .inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
}

.content {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.content h1 {
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    color: #f9f3f4;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 300px #000;
    font-size: 500%;
}

.btn {
    border-radius: 9px;
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    color: white;
    font-size: 135%;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: solid #036AB1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.btn:hover {
    color: #fff;
    border: solid #fff 3px;
}

p {
    font-size: 160%;
    line-height: 200%;
    margin: 3%;
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    padding: 200px;
}


nav ul li {
    position: relative;
    color: red;
    font-size: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Raleway';
    font-weight: 900;



}

nav ul li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;


}

nav ul li a:hover {
    color: blue;

}

.navbar {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;


}

a.btn {
    font-weight: 950;
}

#link {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 100px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

p:first-letter {
    font-size: 200%;
}





article {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

#top1 {

    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;

}

article h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}



#history h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}


#history p {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;    
}
```